# Сравнить даты между собой в одном столбце датафрейма

Tags: python, pandas, дата, datetime

У меня получаются булевые значения, но мне нужно оставить даты и посчитать, сколько их одинаковых.

Пример:

```
[10.10.2021, 10.10.2021, 11.10.2021, 12.10.2021]
```

Желаемый результат

```
[2,1,1]##
```

Код:

```
file_path="E://Jobs//pcap_data//Nan.pcap"
f = open(file_path, 'rb')
list_time = []
pc = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)
for timestamp, packet in pc:
    list_time.append(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",time.localtime(timestamp)))

    new_list =[]
    for i in range(len(list_time)-1):
        new_list.append((list_time[i] == list_time[i+1]))
    new_list
```

Ответ:

```
    {[False,
     True,
     True,
     True,
     True,
     True,
     True,
     True,
     True,
     True,
     False,}
```

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: У меня получается булевые значения, но мне нужно оставить даты и посчитать сколько их одинаковых. Например [10.10.2021, 10.10.2021, 11.10.2021, 12.10.2021] Желаемый результат [2,1,1]

Comment: `groupby(...).count()` используйте или как его там

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Но вроде же это проще несколько делается, спасибо MaxU за пример данных:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'dt': '''\
2021-10-10
2021-10-10
2021-10-10
2021-10-11
2021-10-12
2021-10-12
2021-10-12'''.split('\n')})

res = df.groupby("dt").size().to_list()
print(res)
```

Вывод:

```
[3, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
In [96]: df
Out[96]:
          dt
0 2021-10-10
1 2021-10-10
2 2021-10-10
3 2021-10-11
4 2021-10-12
5 2021-10-12
6 2021-10-12

In [97]: res = df.groupby((df["dt"] != df["dt"].shift()).cumsum())["dt"].count().to_list()

In [98]: res
Out[98]: [3, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Не совсем [10.10.2021, 10.10.2021, 10.10.2021, 11.10.2021, 12.10.2021, 12.10.2021, 12.10.2021] У нас на примере 3 одинаковые даты. А результат должен получится [3, 1, 3] Спасибо

Comment: @МаркАлексеев, исправил ответ. На будущее - приводите воспроизводимые примеры данных и желаемый результат прямо в вопросе

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь. ДА хорошо это первый вопрос был. Спасибо!

Comment: @MaxU Но зачем такие сложности? )  Возможно, я чего-то не понял, но это же явный group by + count, говоря языком SQL :)

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, действительно - чего то я на этом варианте с подсчетом одинаковых и __последовательных__ дат зациклился)